# C program to insert elements into an array until user inputs a 0 or less number

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a C program to insert elements into an array until user inputs a 0 or less number, as the title says. But when I print the array out, it doesn't show the numbers I inputted. I have tried using a `while` as well as `do`-`while` loops but without success.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int data[100];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("Input your number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
        if (data[i] <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    } 
    printf("Your array：");
    int n = sizeof(data[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", &data[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int data[100];
    int i;
    int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("Input your number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
        counter++;
        if (data[i] <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    } 
    printf("Your array：");
    for (int j = 0; j < counter - 1; j++) {
        printf("%d ", data[j]);
        }
}
```

The problem was that you had `printf("%d ", &data[i]);` instead of `printf("%d ", data[i]);`.

And also you've trying to get the `sizeof()` of an element `data[i]`, not the size of the whole array. That's why there's `counter` in my code.

Comment: I see. This solved it. The & really screwed me up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = sizeof(data[i]);
```

this is wrong, you want

```
int n = i;
```

`sizeof(data[i])` gives you the size of an `int` (4 on my machine)

On the other hand, you need to check the result of `scanf`, if a bad input is entered do not increment the counter, something like:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 100)
{
    int res = scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    
    if (res == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (res == 1)
    {
        if (data[i] <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
         // Sanitize stdin
         int c;

         while ((c = getchar()) != '\n');
    }
}
```

Finally, `scanf` wants a pointer to the object, but this is not the case of `printf`:

```
printf("%d ", &data[i])
```

should be

```
printf("%d ", data[i])
```

Comment: Thank you, now I got the right number of array elements to print out. But my problem still stands, it doesn't print out the elements that I inputted. For example:                                                      
Input your number:
7
Input your number:
8
Input your number:
9
Input your number:
10
Input your number:
0
Your array: 7601324 7601328 7601332 7601336

Comment: I can't really downvote I just made this account. Your answer works as well, thanks for your detailed response.